# FTouchManager cause AV when runtime themes are enabled

Tags: delphi, vcl-styles

As I wrote it the title I have a problem with AV caused by FTouchManager when runtime themes are enabled. On main form I have a frame with one button. OnClick event calls main form method which has to destroy frame. If I click on that button I got AV in 'Vcl.Controls'. When I disable runtime themes everything will work ok. How can I solve this problem?

Thank you in advance, Tim

Tested on: Delphi XE3, XE6
Platform: Win32

Vcl.Controls:

```
procedure TWinControl.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
...
WM_MOUSEFIRST..WM_MOUSELAST:
        with FTouchManager do  
          if (GestureEngine <> nil) and (efMouseEvents in GestureEngine.Flags) then // <-- here I get AV error because FTouchManager = nil
            GestureEngine.Notification(Message);
...
end;
```

FrameUnit:

```
constructor TFrame2.Create(AOwner: TWinControl);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  Parent := AOwner;
end;

destructor TFrame2.Destroy;
begin
  Parent := nil;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TFrame2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Form1.DestroyFrame;
end;
```

MainFormUnit:

```
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Frame2 := TFrame2.Create(Form2);
end;

procedure TForm1.DestroyFrame;
begin
    FreeAndNil(Frame2);
end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are destroing the frame and thus the contained button during its OnClick event. So every code inside the button and/or frame instance following the OnClick event references a destroyed self. That doesn't look quite sane to me.

Better post a message to the form (`PostMessage`) that calls DestroyFrame in a message handler.

Comment: Or implement `Release` method for the `TFrame` exactly like `TForm` does via `Postmessage`. Also setting the `Parent` in the constructor does not seem right to me.

Comment: Thank you for help. As you suggested I will use PostMessage. It seems to be that button was destroyed and then it had received one more message which caused AV.